# VBA Cells vs Range - Why is Cells not working?

Tags: vba, excel, range, cells

I have the following code in an excel workbook module. Why don't both E106 and G106 turn yellow??

```
Sub Macro4()
    Worksheets("Thermal Data").Cells(7, 106).Interior.Color = 65535
    Worksheets("Thermal Data").Range("G106").Interior.Color = 65535
End Sub
```

Comment: You have your rows and columns switched `Worksheets("Thermal Data").Cells(106, 7).Interior.Color = 65535`

Comment: Also, `E106` isn't changing as both the commands refer to `G106` (Column 7 is `G`).  Use 5 for column `E` and you'll see it works.

Comment: you could use one line only: `Worksheets("Thermal Data").Range("E106,G106").Interior.Color = 65535`

Answer (score 3):

You should be looking in the wrong cell somewhere. Take a look at this, it works:

```
Sub Macro4()
    Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color = 65535
    Range("A3").Interior.Color = 65535
End Sub
```

Hint - in the cell the first value is the row, then the column.